# Convergence in Distribution Equivalence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Since in my understanding this is quite close to the definition, confusion arises when I want to prove that for a random variables $X_n, n\geq 0$ it holds that:
\begin{align}
X_n \xrightarrow{\text{w}} X \iff \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)],
\end{align}
for all bounded continuous functions $f$.

In order to elaborate this statement, I am thinking about which approach is correct to prove these implications.

For $" \implies"$, one can think about having $\limsup F_n(x) \leq F(x)$ and $\liminf F_n(x) \geq F(x-) = \lim_{y \uparrow x}F(y)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $F_n$ are distributions functions. Concluding that, $\lim F_n(x) = F(x)$ for all $x \in C_F$. However, I am unsure if this is indeed the correct approach for $"\implies"$ and I have no clue for the other implication. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition for $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{w}} X$? The statement you want to prove is one way to DEFINE it, so nothing to prove here ;-)